# float:right sidebar enjoys sitting below my content

Tags: css, html, css-float, sidebar

My side bar seems very comfy sitting *below* my content, to the left hand side of the page. How can I convince it to stay beside it? It is supposed to be to the **right** of the page, with the content to the left. I've been trying previous answers to similar questions and nothing has changed the result I'm getting. [This is what I would like the basic format to appear as.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbMxI.jpg)

CSS:

```
#header {
background-color:#ffffff;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}
#navbar {
background-color:#ffffff;
 color:#000000
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
}
#section {
background-color:#ffffff;
width:500px;
float:left;
padding:10px; 
}
#sidebar {
line-height:30px;
background-color:#14004d;
height:300px;
width:200px;
float:right;
padding:5px; 
}
#footer {
background-color:#14004d;
color:#ffffff;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:5px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

<div id="header">
<h1><center>header image here</center></h1>

<div id="navbar">
<p style="color:#14004d">
Home&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Services&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;     Portfolio&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Testimonials
</p>
</div>

<div id="section">
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<p style="color:#ffffff">
contact info will be listed here.</p>
</div>


<div id="footer">
Copyright © Cassidy v. Ros Online Marketing Solutions 
</div>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3sxn3yaf/

Comment: Does it correct itself if you widen your browser window? Something beyond 756 pixels?

Comment: Is your `#header` element unclosed?

Comment: @NateWhittaker It does, yes.

Comment: Could it be the web host or computer I'm using? I've had 2 friends look at it for me too and no matter how I alter the code it doesn't change the result :/

Comment: it could be if you don't see changes reflected in the page's source. Otherwise, I'd start with making sure your given mark-up is W3C valid before trying to style it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using percentage widths instead (in addition to the `box-sizing` style).

```css
#section {
  /* ... */
  width: 70%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* ... */
}
#sidebar {
  /* ... */
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* ... */
}
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000 text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
#section {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 70%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
#sidebar {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #14004d;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #14004d;
  color: #ffffff;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

  <div id="header">
    <h1><center>header image here</center></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
    <p style="color:#14004d">
      Home&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Services&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Portfolio&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Testimonials
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="section">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <p style="color:#ffffff">
      contact info will be listed here.</p>
  </div>


  <div id="footer">
    Copyright © Cassidy v. Ros Online Marketing Solutions
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: *sigh* This worked in the preview window on here! I was so excited! Buuuut added it in the same way in my web host, and no cigar. The sidebar is still jumping underneath my content.

Comment: Could it be the web host or computer I'm using? I've had 2 friends look at it for me too and no matter how I alter the code it doesn't change the result :/

Comment: It's impossible to say without actually seeing the live site. Alternatively, you could try giving your `body` element a fixed `min-width` style. Something around `756px` might work (https://jsfiddle.net/Ly9fvm7b/).

Answer (score 0):

try to put your sidebar block before your content block.
Like that it will first evaluate the floating view before draw the content element.

Comment: Do you mean within the CSS?

Comment: I tried doing that in the CSS and HTML, neither fixed it. Thank you though!

Comment: Could it be the web host or computer I'm using? I've had 2 friends look at it for me too and no matter how I alter the code it doesn't change the result :/